How to convert the following mixed fraction into improper fraction.$-a \tfrac bc$
This problem is trivial for everyone but I'm confused. I think this problem is not the level of Mathstackexchange.
How to convert the following mixed fraction into improper fraction.$$-a \tfrac bc$$
I think two steps :
(1) $$-a \tfrac bc\ = -a + \frac bc$$
(2) $$-a \tfrac bc\ = -\left(a + \frac bc\right)$$
Out of above steps, which one is correct. Please elaborate it.

the second one is correct, usually we treat $a\frac{b}{c}$ as an entire entity and then you have the minus in front.

"Mixed  fractions" ought to be avoided for several reasons, of which this potential ambiguity is one.  That said,  I would think that the universal convention was to consider the mixed fraction as a single rational number.  Thus $-a\frac bc=-\left(a+\frac bc\right)$.

It's the second one. Mixed fractions is a confusing notation.

The second option, $-a\frac{b}{c}=-\left(a+ \frac{b}{c}\right)$, is correct. Typically you want to avoid using mixed fractions. There is a quick trick to convert any mixed fraction into an improper fraction.
$$A\frac{b}{c}=\frac{(A\times c)+b}{c}$$
This can also be put into words. Given $A\frac{b}{c}$: multiply $c$ and $A$. Now add that number to $b$ and put it on top of the original denominator, $c$.

The second one.
$a\frac{b}{c} = \frac{ac+b}{c}$, which is a single term.
Let $a\frac{b}{c}$ be $x$
$-a\frac{b}{c} = -x = -1(x)$
Substitute it back,
$\begin{align}
-1(x) = -1(a\frac{b}{c})
= -1(\frac{ac+b}{c}) = -1(\frac{ac}{c} + \frac{b}{c}) = -1(a+\frac{b}{c})
\end{align}$
However, I would not recommend using mixed fraction. It is confusing and ambiguous. At the first sight without reading the question, I almost thought the meaning of your notation $a\frac{b}{c}$ to be $a\times\frac{b}{c}$.
